# SUM total result in while loop (Settled)

Tags: php, sql, select

I need to calculate a totalsum in while loop. I tried various solution but I'm still not getting any result. Can you guys can suggest any ideas to me?

The problem is once I get '$section_total' I would like to sum section_total and come out the output in $totalsum. I also tired $toalsum += $section_total;

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$totalsum=0;

$sql = "SELECT  form_details_section_id,SUM(mark),COUNT(mark) FROM audit_section_markrecord WHERE audit_section_id = '$audit_no' GROUP BY form_details_section_id ";

$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 

    $query1 = "SELECT * FROM form_details_section WHERE id = '$row[form_details_section_id]' ";
    $result1 = $db->query($query1);
    $row1 = $result1->fetch_array();

    $query6 = "SELECT COUNT(mark) FROM audit_section_markrecord WHERE `form_details_section_id` = '$row[form_details_section_id]' ";
    $result6 = $db->query($query6);
    $row6 = $result6->fetch_array();    

    $mark = $row['SUM(mark)'];
    $final_mark = $row1['final_mark'];
    $section_mark = $row6['COUNT(mark)'];
    $sub = ($section_mark*10);
    $subtotal = ($mark/$sub);
    $section_total = round($subtotal*$final_mark);
    echo"
    <tr class='odd gradeX'>
    <td>".$j."</td>
    <td>".$row1['category']."</td>
    <td>$section_total</td>
    ";
    $j++;

}
?>
</tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="right">Total Score:</td>
    <td><?php $totalsum ?></td>
```

Comment: `$mark = $mark + $row['mark'];` try this.

Comment: @ShiguriAnemone' not getting answer too. In my sql, I am only store each mark; that is the point I use SUM() to total up the mark and pass to another variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $section_total = round($subtotal*$final_mark);
 //After above line in your existing code. Write code as below.
 $totalsum += $section_total;
```

Comment: Same too bro. return empty result.

Comment: Can you post here what value you get in $row , $row1 and $row6

Comment: bro, everything works! I don't know what happen previously :( Thank alot! You are awesome (y)

Answer (score 0):

Add `$totalsum` at your while loop,
Put it after `$j++;`

`$totalsum = $totalsum + $whateverYouWantToAdd;`

Comment: return empty result bro.